# Update .NET Compact Framework - when?

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

As many of you know, in Barcelona last week at the Mobile World Congress, Microsoft presented a "beta" of Windows Mobile 6.5 which will probably be launched later on this year.

I have been reading a lot of articles on the web about this congress and the new features of Windows Mobile 6.5 but nowhere have I found any indications if the .NET Compact Framework (currently at 3.5) will be updated as well.

Does anyone of you have any news/updates in this regard which you would like to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you shouldn't hold your breath. I really don't think there's anything new for 6.5 concerning .NET CF, but for 7.0 I'd say that a new .NET CF will be in ROM.

Comment: I agree with you i.e. we won't see anything until version 7.0 however after seeing the new interface (which is rather different from previous versions), I thought there might some new features "under the hood".